# Is it possible to use child theme of child them?

Tags: themes, child-theme

I am using [iStore](https://wordpress.org/themes/istore/) free WordPress theme for a website. It is a child theme of [MaxStore](https://wordpress.org/themes/maxstore/).

Now I need to modify the iStore themes. Since iStore is a already child theme, I don't know that is it possible to create a child theme of iStore ?

Is it possible? If not what is the alternative way to change child theme?

Comment: No. There’s no such thing as grandchild themes.

Comment: What do you want to create the child theme for? Most things can be done from a plugin.

Comment: @gmazzap I just wanted to change the layout of the single page... need to display the last modified date instead of update date... Need to remove the written by name part.... Can those things done using a plugin?

Comment: Yes, those things can be done via a plugin. It could be from very easy to very hard depending on how things are actually done in the theme. You could open a new question asking _"I'm using this child theme that do this, how can I change it from a plugin (because it is not possible to use grandchild thems?)"_. I think that could be interesting question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible?

No. There's no such things as grandchild themes.

> If not what is the alternative way to change child theme?

Many things can be done from plugins. It could be from very easy to very hard depending on how things are actually done in the theme.